# if insert contains certain char then replace with different char

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE Example
(
ID int,
MyChar char(1)
);

INSERT INTO Example (ID, MyChar)
VALUES ('1','[');
```

Can I somehow intercept this insert so that 'a' will be inserted into MyChar instead of '['?

I could write a trigger to do an update **after** the row has been created but that seems messy. Is there a way to do this at the point of the insert?

Note: I cannot change the insert statement which is sent to the db because this is sent by an app outside of my control.

Edit: apologies - this relates to Microsoft SQL Server (2008)

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: Triggers seem about the only way I can think of, if you can't solve this in another layer.

Comment: Some (but not all!) Database engines supports i instead of / before triggers. Some of them also have a built in replace method. If you add the tag of the releant rdbms, This could be an easy question to answer.

Comment: Apologies - this relates to Microsoft SQL Server, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql Server supports [instead of insert triggers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx) as well as `replace`, that's basically all you need for this requirement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Example_InsteadOfInsert ON Example
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS

INSERT INTO Example (ID, MyChar)
SELECT ID, 
       REPLACE(MyChar, '[', 'a')
FROM inserted;

GO
```

If you want to replace multiple chars with multiple replacements, you can nest replace statements:

```
SELECT ID, 
       REPLACE(
               REPLACE(MyChar, '[', 'a')
               ,']', 'b')
FROM inserted;
```

Comment: This worked exactly as I needed and is much better than updating after the insert which is what I was going to do. Much appreciated.